IsoformSwitchAnalyzeR in R
I want to find isoform switches for a disease and I have the RNASeq expression data file (it's a CSV file with info about the 2 stages I want to compare and study). The RNASeq was done using Kallisto. I read the official pdf for this library called "IsoformSwitchAnalyzeR" but I'm not quite able to understand what I'm supposed to do. I need to create a "switchAnalyzeRlist" object using a function called "createSwitchAnalyzeRlist()" as shown below:
createSwitchAnalyzeRlist(
    isoformFeatures,
    exons,
    designMatrix,
    isoformCountMatrix=NULL,
    isoformRepExpression=NULL,
    sourceId,
    removeFusionTranscripts = TRUE
)

However, I don't have the files that its description suggests I need (like exons, etc).
I tried reading more on how to import the data and everything but all in vain. Could someone please help me with this?
